# UWP-CPP/Winrt Set Corner radius of the ListViewItem when hovered/selected

Tags: xaml, listview, uwp, listviewitem, c++-winrt

I am planning to show a list of objects using ListView. According to the design the rectangle around the ListViewItem should be rounded at the corners. Have tried multiple ways to achieve the same but couldn't find a solution.

```
                    <ListView
                    x:Name="ObjectList"
                    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ObjectViewModel.Objects}"
                    SelectionChanged="ListViewButtonClick"
                    MaxWidth ="{StaticResource ColumnMaximumWidth}"
                    VerticalAlignment = "Center"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment = "Stretch"
                    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility ="Disabled"
                    SelectionMode ="Single" />

                    <ListView.Resources>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemBackgroundSelected" Color="Green" />
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver" Color="Green" />
                    </ListView.Resources>

                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,30" />
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ObjectModel">
                            <Border
                                BorderBrush="Red"
                                BorderThickness="3"
                                CornerRadius="5">
                                <Grid MinHeight="66" CornerRadius="8">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <FontIcon
                                        FontSize="17"
                                        Glyph="&#xE720;"
                                        Style="{StaticResource FontIconStyle1}" />
                                    <TextBlock
                                        Grid.Column="1"
                                        Style="{StaticResource AddBluetoothLabelTextStyle}"
                                        Text="{x:Bind ObjectName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

[image: As shown in the below picture the corners of the selected/hovered items is not rounded]

As shown in the picture the corners of the selected/hovered items is not rounded. Can you please help how this can be achieved. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `VisualState` to set `CornerRadius` of `ListViewItem` in style of `ListViewItem`.

Please check the following steps:

1. Open `generic.xaml` file, find a `Style` whose `TargetType` is `ListViewItem` and `Key` is `ListViewItemRevealStyle`. Copy the style into your `Page.Resources`.
2. Delete the `x:Key` property of the style so that the style could be used in all `ListViewItem` in the current Page.
3. Find a `VisualState` whose name is `Selected`, add the following code:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Selected">  
    <VisualState.Setters>
        <Setter Target="Root.CornerRadius" Value="10" />
    </VisualState.Setters>
</VisualState>
```

4. Find `VisualState`s whose names are `PointerOver`, `PointerOverSelected`, `PointerOverPressed`, `PointerOverPressed`, add the following code seperately:

```
<Setter Target="Root.CornerRadius" Value="10" />  <!--Add this code-->
```

5. Delete the `ListView.ItemContainerStyle` statement, which conflicts with the `ListViewItem’s` style.

Note, it is better if you could follow the above steps first to set corner radius in the style of `ListViewItem` then add other style or settings later, which could ensure settings in the style of `ListViewItem` work.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. It really helped a lot, may I know how to approach these kind of situations or can you point me to any resources which explains how to do advanced styling in XAML.

Comment: You could try to learn the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/xaml-styles) about [Style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.style?view=winrt-19041), the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/control-templates) about [control template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.controltemplate?view=winrt-19041) and [VisualState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.visualstate?view=winrt-19041).

Comment: And the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/item-containers-templates) about item containers and templates.